# Finding a sequence of functions which converge to the derivative of the Dirac delta

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory

I am looking for a sequence of functions $K_n(x)$ with 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}K_n(x)f(x)\mathrm dx=f'(0)
$$
for a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
I have just proven (another sub part of the problem) that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\frac{n}{2}\cos (nx) f(x)\mathrm dx=f(0)
$$
through a change of variables and integration by parts. Is there an obvious way to modify the above solution I am missing? Is there perhaps a Fourier series solution?

Thanks for any hints and help!

edit: 
Here is the solution to the first part of the problem
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\frac{n}{2}\cos (nx) f(x)\mathrm dx\stackrel{\text{IBP}}=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{2}\left[  \frac{1}{n}(f(x)\sin(nx)\vert_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}-\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}f'(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm dx \right]\\
=f(0)-\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}f'(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm dx 
$$
but the final integral tends to $0$, since 
$$
\left| \frac{1}{n}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}f'(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm dx \right |\leq \\
\bigg | \frac{\pi}{n^2}\sup_{x\in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]} f'(x) \bigg |\to 0
$$

Comment: What happens if you use [some multiple of] $\sin(nx)$ in place of $\cos(nx)$?

Comment: @GEdgar your hint was perfect, I got it using $\sin(nx)\frac{n^2}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the computation already, but I'll explain the situation in general. Suppose that functions $\phi_n$ converge to the Dirac $\delta$ in the sense of distributions, meaning 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_n(x)f(x)\, dx  = f(0)
$$
for smooth compactly supported functions $f$. Then the functions $\psi_n = -\phi_n'$, with the derivative understood in the sense of distributions, satisfy
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi_n(x)f(x)\, dx  = f'(0)
$$
The reason is integration by parts: $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(-\phi_n(x))'f(x)\, dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_n(x)f'(x)\, dx \to f'(0)$.

In your situation $\phi_n(x) = \frac{n}{2} \cos nx$ restricted to $|x|<\pi/(2n)$. This is a continuous piecewise smooth function, so its distributional derivative is the same as the regular one: $\psi_n(x) = -\phi_n'(x) = \frac{n^2}{2} \sin nx$  restricted to $|x|<\pi/(2n)$.

And since $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ are compactly supported, it does not matter whether $f$ is compactly supported; smoothness is enough.

Comment: thank you for showing me what's actually going on here! +1

Comment: Does the sequence of spikes work? The sequence is given by: $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n-n^2x & 0<x<\frac{1}{n}\\ n+n^2x & -\frac{1}{n}<x<0\\ 0 & |x|\geq\frac{1}{n}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I can seem to show that this sequence satisfies: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\cdot\phi(x) dx\rightarrow \delta_0$$ But I can't show that the derivative $-f'_n(x)=g_n(x)$ completes the other requirement that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_n(x)\cdot\phi(x)\rightarrow \delta'_0$$... @Desire

Comment: @FelicioGrande Yes, it works. $\int g_n\phi = \int f_n \phi'$ (integration by parts), and the latter converges to $\phi'(0)$.

Comment: I think its also important to note though that $\phi'(0)=-\delta_0'$ though, no? @Desire

Comment: No, $\phi'(0)$ is a number, it's not the distribution $-\delta_0'$.  Rather, the linear functional $\phi \mapsto \phi'(0)$ is the distribution $-\delta_0'$. I didn't see it important to mention this because when someone asks "how to prove that A converges to B", I assume they know what B means. Otherwise they are asking the wrong question.